# Creating a CKAN package/dataset with resources using ckanapi and Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, ckan

CKAN provides the [`ckanapi`](https://github.com/ckan/ckanapi#file-uploads) package for accessing [the CKAN API](http://docs.ckan.org/en/latest/api/#ckan.logic.action.create.package_create) via Python or the command line.

I can use it to download metadata, create resources, etc. But I can't create a package and upload resources to it in a single API call. (A package is also referred to as a dataset.)

Internally, `ckanapi` [scans all keys moving any file-like parameters into a separate `dict`](https://github.com/ckan/ckanapi/blob/master/ckanapi/common.py#L39), which it [passes to the `requests.session.post(files=..)` parameter](https://github.com/ckan/ckanapi/blob/master/ckanapi/remoteckan.py#L86).

This is the closest I can get but CKAN returns an HTTP 500 error (copied from [this guide to `requests`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#post-a-multipart-encoded-file)):

```
with ckanapi.RemoteCKAN('http://myckan.example.com', apikey='real-key', user_agent=ua, username='joe', password='pwd') as ckan:
    ckan.action.package_create(name='joe_data',
                               resources=('report.xls',
                                          open('/path/to/file.xlsx', 'rb'),
                                          'application/vnd.ms-excel',
                                          {'Expires': '0'}))
```

I've also tried `resources=open('path/file')`, `files=open('file')`, shorter or longer tuples, but get the same 500 error.

The `requests` documentation says:

```
:param files: (optional) Dictionary of ``'filename': file-like-objects``
    for multipart encoding upload.
```

I can't pass `ckanapi` `resources={'filename': open('file')}` as `ckanapi` doesn't detect the file, attempts to pass it to `requests` as a normal parameter, and fails ("BufferedReader is not JSON serializable" as it attempts to make the file a `POST` parameter). I get the same if I try to pass a list of files. But [the API is able to](http://docs.ckan.org/en/latest/api/#ckan.logic.action.create.package_create) create a package and add a number of resources in a single call.

So how do I create a package and multiple resources with a single `ckanapi` call?

Comment: If it is not possible, suggestions for a pull request to `ckanapi` very welcome. What format and code change definitely won't break existing uses of the file handling code I link to? Is there a 'canonical' list of target use cases?

Comment: Curious if you figured this out? I think the general approach is to make 2 calls, 1 to create the package and 1 to create the resource. Once the package is created you have the info to create a resource and tie to a package, as resources need the url and package id. `package_create` returns the package by default (or optionally the id).

Answer (score 0):

I was curious about this and thought I'd put something together to test it. Unfortunately I haven't played with the CLI you mentioned. But I hope this will help you and others stumbling across this.

I am not positive but I'm guessing your resource dict isn't formatted properly. The resources needs to be a list of dictionaries.

**Here's a ruby script to do the single api call insert (my preferred language at this time):**

```
# Ruby script to create a package and resource in one api call. 
# You can run this in https://repl.it/languages/ruby
# Don't forget to update URLs and API key.
require 'csv'
require 'json'
require 'net/http'

hash_to_json = {
                  "title" => 'test1',
                  "name" => 'test1',
                  "owner_org" => 'bbb9682e-b58c-4826-bf4b-b161581056be',
                  "resources" => [ 
                    {
                      "url" => 'http://www.resource_domain.com/doc.kml'
                    }
                  ]
                }.to_json

uri = URI('http://ckan_app_domain.com:5000/api/3/action/package_create')

Net::HTTP.start(uri.host, uri.port) do |http|
  request = Net::HTTP::Post.new uri

  request['Authorization'] = 'user-api-key'
  request.body = hash_to_json

  response = http.request request
  puts response.body
end
```

**And here's a plain python script to do the same thing (thank you CKAN docs for this template I modified)**

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import urllib2
import urllib
import json
import pprint

# Put the details of the dataset we're going to create into a dict.
dataset_dict = {
    'name': 'my_dataset_name',
    'notes': 'A long description of my dataset',
    'owner_org': 'bbb9682e-b58c-4826-bf4b-b161581056be',
    'resources': [
      {
        'url': 'example.com'
      }
    ]
}

# Use the json module to dump the dictionary to a string for posting.
data_string = urllib.quote(json.dumps(dataset_dict))

# We'll use the package_create function to create a new dataset.
request = urllib2.Request(
    'http://ckan_app_domain.com:5000/api/3/action/package_create')

# Creating a dataset requires an authorization header.
# Replace *** with your API key, from your user account on the CKAN site
# that you're creating the dataset on.
request.add_header('Authorization', 'user-api-key')

# Make the HTTP request.
response = urllib2.urlopen(request, data_string)
assert response.code == 200

# Use the json module to load CKAN's response into a dictionary.
response_dict = json.loads(response.read())
assert response_dict['success'] is True

# package_create returns the created package as its result.
created_package = response_dict['result']
pprint.pprint(created_package)
```

Comment: Thanks very much for looking into this. However it is the `ckanapi` package that is the issue. I included a link to the correctly working API endpoint in my answer, but the `ckanapi` package does some re-structuring of the file data before passing on the request, which breaks it, and I can't find a way of using `ckanapi` that does not cause it to break the request.